# Tricky Normal Distribution Question!

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The flourescent light tubes made by the company Well-lit have lifetimes which are normally distributed with mean 2010 hours and standard deviation 20 hours. The company decides to promote its sales of the tubes by guaranteeing a minimum life of the tubes, replacing free of charge any tubes that fail to meet this minimum life. If the company wishs to have to replace only 3% of the tubes sold, find the guaranteed minimum it must set.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Dumbfuzzled, Tried doing P(X>97) but you get a silly answer, more tricky then generic Normal Distribution Problem

Comment: I'd start by drawing a normal curve and shade in the area corresponding to lightbulbs that were going to be replaced.

Comment: So just 3% of the area underneath the curve, how would you work that out and why?

Comment: Use a z-table backwards, if that's what you use.  This gives you a z-score cutoff, which in turn can get you to a raw-score cutoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at a standard normal table, at which value does the probability surpass 97%?

It's when you ask the deviation to be less than 1.89 times the standard deviation.

By symmetry the probability that a standard normal is more than -1.89 times the standard deviation is nearly 97%.

Our lamp duration have mean 2010 and standard deviation 20, that is $T=2010+20N$ where $N$ is a standard normal. So $P(T<1972.2)=P(N<-1.89)\approx 3\%$.
Hence 1972.2 is the safe choice.